# Constructing pointer linked list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

If i initialize the list in main it works like charm but I can't add to an empty list. Why not?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct liste{

    int a;
    struct liste *next;
};


void AddEnd( int val, struct liste* l )
{

    struct liste *aux;
    struct liste *n;

    n=(struct liste*) malloc (sizeof(struct liste));
    n->a = val;
    n->next = NULL;

    aux=l;
    if(aux == NULL)
    {
        l=n;
    }
    else
    {
        while(aux->next != NULL)
        aux=aux->next;
        aux->next=n;  
    }

}

void DeleteHead(struct liste* l){

    struct liste *aux=l;
    if (aux!=NULL)
    {

        l=l->next;
        free(aux);  
    }
}
void Print ( struct liste* l)

{
  printf("the list contains:  \n ");

    while(l!=NULL)
    {

        printf("%d | ",l->a);
        l = l->next;
    }

}



void main() {

    struct liste* nl;
    AddEnd(9,nl);
    AddEnd(8,nl);
    AddEnd(7,nl);
    DeleteHead(nl);

    Print(nl);

}
```

Comment: why doesn't it add elements to the list? (if i initialize the list in main it works like charm but not with an empty list)..need your help please!!!

Comment: That comment should be *in* your question.

Comment: [you're reinventing the wheel here man... Check this link out, it will have your answer.](http://www.redbrick.dcu.ie/~c-hey/src/c-hey2.0/g_list.c)

Comment: If you don't initialize the list, it doesn't start empty: it starts uninitialized (so anything can happen depending on what happens to be in that memory location). To initialize an empty list, write `struct liste *nl = NULL`.

Comment: @Mike Building a wheel that others have invented is a necessary learning exercise.

Comment: @Gilles I was by no means saying that he should stop, just saying that there are plenty of answers on the web, coming to Stackoverflow for answers that can be easily found on the web is poor form, you should be able to find easy answers like this without the need of SO's help.

Comment: Is it C or C++. Either way you get a +1 for at least trying your homework

Comment: `l=n;` at `AddEnd` : change local variable. not change original.

Comment: This is a duplicate of goodness only knows how many questions.  The difficulty is finding them, especially when reviewing in the 'close' queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since parameters in c passed by value, changes done on struct liste * l not reflected in main function.
Either return pointer to head of your list from AddEnd function i.e.

```
struct liste * AddEnd( int val, struct liste* l )
{
 .....
    if(aux == NULL)
    {
       *l=n;

    }
    else 
    {
           while(aux->next != NULL)
           aux=aux->next;
           aux->next=n;  
    }
    return l;
```

and then in main function

```
 nl = AddEnd(nl);
```

either pass pointer to head of your list

Answer (score 0):

You should use a pointer to pointer to modify you “nl” in the function "AddEnd":

```
void AddEnd( int val, struct liste** l )
{

    struct liste *aux;
    struct liste *n;

    n=(struct liste*) malloc (sizeof(struct liste));
    n->a = val;
    n->next = NULL;

    aux=*l;
    if(aux == NULL)
    {
        *l=n;
    }
    else
    {
        while(aux->next != NULL)
        aux=aux->next;
        aux->next=n;  
    }

}
```

And also need such kind of change:

```
void main() {

    struct liste* nl = NULL;
    AddEnd(9, &nl);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function parameter l is a local variable of the function. So any changes of this variable within the function does not influence on the original argument.

Change the function the following way

```
void AddEnd( int val, struct liste **l )
{
    struct liste *n = (struct liste*) malloc( sizeof( struct liste ) );
    n->a = val;
    n->next = NULL;

    if ( *l == NULL )
    {
        *l = n;
    }
    else
    {
        struct liste *aux = *l;
        while ( aux->next != NULL ) aux = aux->next;
        aux->next = n;  
    }
}
```

Also in main you at first delete the list and after that you try to print it. I think that you meant

```
int main( void ) {

    struct liste* nl;

    AddEnd( 9, &nl );
    AddEnd( 8, &nl );
    AddEnd( 7, &nl );

    Print(nl);

    DeleteHead(nl);
}
```

Also take into account that main in C shall be declared as

```
int main( void )
```